# Not getting redirected back to the updated blog post in django

Tags: javascript, python, css, django

i have a single Blog,i am trying to only have a detailview,but when i add new post it will only show the pagination,but the post will already be added to my blogpost not until i go to the blog home page,even when i search for a blogpost e.g http://127.0.0.1:8000/pages/blog/22/?= i wont get what i want

##views.py

```
class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'pages/blog.html'
    context_object_name = 'blog'
    ordering = ['-timestamp']
```

##urls.py

```
    path('blog/', blog, name='blog'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>/', BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='blog'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created a listview and detailview separately, with a diffrent URL

```
class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'pages/blog.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'blog_post'
    ordering = ['-timestamp']
    paginate_by = 5


class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Blog
```